# Invalid result code for Wi-Fi information request - Flutter iOS - ConnectSDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, flutter, live-connect-sdk

We have a Flutter app where we implemented the ConnectSDK with Objective-C platform code. On the iOS Simulator devices are detected but on a physical device we get: `nehelper sent invalid result code [1] for Wi-Fi information request` and no devices are detected.

We checked the following:

- `NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription` is in the plist.
- `Access Wi-Fi Information` Entitlement is enabled under Signing and Capabilities and on the Identifier.
- Tried enabling `Network Extensions`.
- Tried requesting location access permission and setting `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription`, `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`, `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in the plist.
- The native popup to allow network access does not appear and using the `permission_handler` we see that all permissions including Notifications and Location is set to permanently denied. Local Network Access is enabled in Settings.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey Jaco, did you solve this?

Comment: Hi @iDec, we were not able to resolve this. We dropped the ConnectSDK library as a result and used the `flutter_cast_video` and `flutter_ios_airplay` plugins instead.